# AJP could not acquire lock to page, PageAccessSynchronizer warning

Tags: java, tomcat, wicket, ajp

I recently found these warnings in our logs. I am not an expert on threading or tomcat. Does anyone have some advice on how to debug this problem?

We are running a wicket application on a tomcat server. Let me know if any other information would be useful. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
[Jun 24, 2014 11:28:40] WARN [org.apache.wicket.page.PageAccessSynchronizer]
- Thread 'ajp-   bio-8009-exec-26' failed to acquire lock to page with id '4',
attempted for 1 minute out of allowed 1 minute. The thread that holds the 
lock has name 'ajp-bio-8009-exec-20'.

[Jun 24, 2014 11:28:40] WARN [org.apache.wicket.page.PageAccessSynchronizer]
- "ajp-bio-8009-exec-20" daemon prio=5 tid=40 state=RUNNABLE
```

Comment: I found that I could dump the tomcat thread log in ubuntu by using kill -3 which has provided some insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem once on a page with a very long database query. The query was expected to be long so the 1+ minute load time for that page was expected. But if I clicked to an other page, that page will load after the first one and will time-out if it doesn't start loading within a minute, and here I got the same error as you had.

I solved this by using Lazy loading of my long database query page. An example of [AjaxLazyLoadPanel](https://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/extensions/ajax/markup/html/AjaxLazyLoadPanel.html) is [here](http://www.mkyong.com/wicket/how-do-use-ajaxlazyloadpanel-in-wicket/).

Second thing you can do is what [svenmeier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24395845/2452275) suggested and increase the timeout like so:

```
getRequestCycleSettings().setTimeout(Duration.minutes(3));
```

This will still make the second request wait for the first one but Wicket gives it more time.

Comment: This is exactly what was happening. A query was taking 193 seconds to execute. I solved the problem by rewriting the extremely inefficient query to take 2 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

While a page is processed, Wicket will keep all further request waiting. These will give up after a configurable IRequestCycleSettings#timeout().

Check why your page takes so long to respond.